# Balancing between filter and getting the name of foreign key in eloquent

Tags: filtering, laravel-8

I have a controller that will list all items like this:

```
$users = User::all();
return view('auth.userslist', compact('users'));
```

And In my Users Model, function that will display the name of foreign key items:

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Roles');
}
```

Displayed in blade like this:

```
<td>{{$user->name}}</td>
<td>{{$user->role->role_name}}</td>
```

Which works fine. Now, I want to add a filter for my user list(Active and Inactive). Based on docs, I need to do it like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('user_delete', '=', 0)
    ->get();
return view('auth.userslist', ['users' => $users]);
```

But it will return an error message `Undefined property: stdClass::$role`. If I remove all the foreign key fields, it will filter just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `with()` or `join`

```
$users = User::with('role')->where('user_delete', '=', 0)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)